# How does this library work? JsonEngine

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, rest

https://code.google.com/p/jsonengine/

I have uploaded it to my app engine, I can see the [Admin Panel](https://code.google.com/p/jsonengine/wiki/HowToAdmin) but i'm not sure how I can use it to make json requests.

Do I have to write my own classes or does it do it automatically?

Can someone explain to me how this library works. I have read the wiki many times and I don't get it.

Can I use this library to make json requests from my mobile app to list/update/create records on the server?

Comment: You have three different questions here.
The first two of them should be answered with "try googling JsonEngine and see what you can find yourself". The other should be a question on its own.

Answer (score 4):

JSONEngine is a RESTful database. It is not a library to *make* JSON requests, it is a library to *store/retrieve/handle* JSON requests. Its not a library, its a server.

You can read/write data to it by making HTTP calls, as documented in their [Usage Guide](https://code.google.com/p/jsonengine/wiki/HowToUse). Its *up to you* to decide how (or what library) that you want to save/retrieve data from this JSONEngine. There are dozens of Java libraries for accessing REST API, such as [UniRest](http://unirest.io/) for example.

| Can I use this library to make json requests from my mobile app to list/update/create records on the server?

Nope, again this is not a library, its a server. You can use any Java REST library to make calls to store/retrieve data from this JSONEngine server.

EDIT: Additional clarification

Comment: I don't understand your first and second paragraphs. Can you give me an example usage of this server? what do you store in it and why?